# Listar datos de tabla SQL en proyecto Angular

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Veran, he desarrollado ultimamente un proyecto Angular/Bootstrap estilo blog, algo sencillo.
La cuestion es que, por tema de costos, he decidido usar una base de datos SQL.

Intente inyectando php directo en los templates (cambiando las extensiones de los archivos de html a php) pero solo me he dado contra la pared.

He leido de proyectos que han hecho esta vinculacion, asi que SE que se puede hacer, pero no entiendo como.

Reitero, la parte visual ya esta creada, la base de datos tambien, mi problema es como trabajar con php en angular, como se hace?

Comment: Has una petición Ajax entonces regresas los datos y los iteras

Comment: Por lo que he leido tiene algo que ver con los servicios de Angular. Soy nuevo al respecto, te agradeceria si pudieras enviarme algun link a video o post donde expliquen mejor como hacerlo.

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y puede terminar cerrada por ser basada en opiniones ahora Ajax no es un término de angular, solo busca como implementarlo en dicho framework